# navigationController won't return to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, cocoapods

I have imported a third party library into my project.  In my AppDelegate i create a navigationController and set the rootViewController to my existing project main view.  Then I reference the library ViewController and present it on the navigation stack (i think). It gets displayed but when i try to dismiss and go back to my original project view it doesn't not work.  My Code:

AppDelegate.m

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        appbarViewController = [[AppBarViewController alloc] init];
        self.navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:appbarViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigation;
        [self.navigation setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        [self.window addSubview:self.navigation.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        }
        return YES;
    }

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
if([[url host] isEqualToString:@"session"]){

        if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/login"])
        {

    ACSViewController *acs = [[ACSViewController alloc] init];     
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:acs animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

ACSViewController is not part of the library, i created and from within the library class is called.

libraryViewController.m

```
-(void)backButtonPressed
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any ideas why the view will not dismiss? It animates away but then returns with the same current view.

Comment: Do you push the view or use the presentViewController?

Comment: show me the coding of presentViewcontroller.

Comment: present, sorry i was on the same line.  I've moved it now so can see how i present the view

Comment: it's in the above code, this line [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:acs animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: Seriously there is no option.Because you write the coding directly from openURL.First you need to go to another view only from the RootViewController not in appDelegate.M

Comment: I'm using deep links. I've updated my question to show exactly what is happening in openURL

Comment: Try to send the `dismissViewControllerAnimated::` message to the same view controller object that you used with `presentViewController:::`, you might be sending it to another object now. Also, I believe that the line with `self.window addSubview` is excessive as you've already set the desired view controller as the root view controller.

Comment: how would i write that? could you give me a code example, would i use something like [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]

Answer (score 0):

You are `dismissing` `viewcontroller` which has `not` been `presented` so animation happens but returns with same view.

Here you are presenting `ACSViewController` and dismissing `libraryViewController`.

Solution is firstly remove libraryViewController's view and then dismiss ACSViewController. The below line of code should be in `ACSViewController` to dismiss it.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot import my Project headers into the library.  But I can add to the library.  Would [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: be suitable for this or not good practice?